# Differences between these representations of classification problems in probability terms

Tags: probability, classification, density-function

Say that $\mathcal{X}$ is the set of observations, and $\mathcal{Y}$ is the set of classification labels.

Also say that $X$ is a continuous random variable that takes values in $\mathcal{X}$, and $Y$ is a discrete random variable that takes values in $\mathcal{Y}$.

Then for a testing sample $x\in\mathcal{X}$, I find that text books often define classification tasks in probability terms as follows:
$$
\hat y_1 = \underset{y\in\mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} \Pr(Y=y|X=x)
$$

**Questions:** Is there any difference between $\hat y_1$ and these:
$$
\hat y_2 = \underset{y\in\mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} \Pr(Y=y,X=x)
$$

$$
\hat y_3 = \underset{y\in\mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} f_{Y,X}(y,x)
$$

$$
\hat y_4 = \underset{y\in\mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} f_{Y|X=x}(y)
$$

$$
\hat y_5 = \underset{y\in\mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} f_{Y=y|X}(x)
$$

where $f_{X,Y}$, $f_{X|Y}$, and $f_{Y|X}$ are joined and conditioned probability density functions.

- Are there any differences?
- If so, what are they?
- If not, why do most (all from the little that I have seen) text books show $\hat y_1$ and not the others?

---

## Below is my attempt:

I think I have only managed to show that:

- $\hat y_2 = \hat y_1$.
- $\hat y_5 = \hat y_1$ only if $Y$ is uniformly distributed.

I still can't show for the rest. I also need confirmation on whether what I did below is right.

#### Does $\hat y_2 = \hat y_1$?

Let's start from here:
$$
\hat y_2 = \underset{y \in \mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} \Pr(Y=y, X=x)
$$

From there, we can manipulate around and achieve the following:
$$\require{cancel}\begin{split}
\hat y_2 &= \underset{y \in \mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} \Pr(Y=y, X=x)\\
         &= \underset{y \in \mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} \cancel{\Pr(X=x)}\Pr(Y=y | X=x) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(since $\Pr(X=x)$ is constant)}\\
\hat y_1 &= \underset{y \in \mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} \Pr(Y=y | X=x)\\
\end{split}$$

So we confirm that $\hat y_2 = \hat y_1$.

#### Does $\hat y_5 = \hat y_1$?

$$\require{cancel}\begin{split}
\hat y_1 &= \underset{y \in \mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} \Pr(Y=y | X=x)\\
         &= \underset{y \in \mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} \frac{\Pr(Y=y)\Pr(X=x|Y=y)}{\Pr(X=x)} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(bayesian rule)}\\
         &= \underset{y \in \mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} \lim_{d \rightarrow 0}\frac{\Pr(Y=y) \big(d \times f_{X|Y=y}(x)\big)}{\big(d\times f_X(x)\big)}\\
         &= \underset{y \in \mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} \lim_{d \rightarrow 0}\frac{\Pr(Y=y) \big(\cancel{d} \times f_{X|Y=y}(x)\big)}{\big(\cancel{d}\times f_X(x)\big)}\\
         &= \underset{y \in \mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} \frac{\Pr(Y=y) f_{X|Y=y}(x)}{\cancel{f_X(x)}} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(since $f_X(x)$ is constant)}\\
\hat y_5 &= \underset{y \in \mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg max }} \cancel{\Pr(Y=y)} f_{X|Y=y}(x) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(by assuming $Y$ is uniformly distributed)}\\
\end{split}$$

So we confirm that $\hat y_5 = \hat y_1$ is true **only** when $Y$ is uniformly distributed, I.e. $\Pr(Y=y_1) = \Pr(Y=y_2) = \ldots = \Pr(Y=y_n)$.

Comment: I am not sure what this is but Pr(Y=y,X=x) is a joint probability for discrete variables and Pr(Y=y|X=x) is a conditional probability for discrete variables.  I don't see why you are mentioning continuous distributions.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Not sure if I am following. Just to troubleshoot: Did you get that $X$ is a contentious random variable?

Comment: Adding to what @MichaelChernick said, are $X$ and $Y$ discrete or continuous?

Comment: @Tim $X$ is continuous, $Y$ is discrete.

Comment: @caveman then your first representation does not make sense since P(X=x) = 0...

Comment: @Tim Why? $Y$ is discrete as I said. I don't see why $\Pr(Y=y)$ has to be $0$. Unless I'm missing something deeper?

Comment: @Tim Hmm interesting. I will ask a separate question about that. I have some justifications, but I think maybe I am not fully understanding. Thank you for raising this up.

Comment: @Tim Here is the other question that branched out of this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251077/is-pry-yx-x-defined